# Error when running rails g rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

I destroyed my User and Role models with `rails destroy model <model_name>` and tried to run `rails g rolify Role User`, but I am getting the error

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get': uninitialized constant User (NameError)
```

Along with a big regurgitation of other information. What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` model/class needs to exist.